# Hide debug messages from FeedbackMessageFilter in wicket 1.5 during production?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

In developing some of my Web Applications I use `debug("stuff here");` to help me figure out whats going on.  I'd rather not have to go in and find all of my `debug(*);` lines and remove them. Is there a way I can specify at the application level not to display debug messages in a `FeedBackPanel`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add an [ErrorLevelFeedbackMessageFilter](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/feedback/ErrorLevelFeedbackMessageFilter.html) to your FeedbackPanels (there is a constructor accepting one). If you create the filter based on your deployment mode, this should be what you need.

In Detail:

Change your `new FeedbackPanel("id")` to `new FeedbackPanel("id", Application.getFeedbackMessageFilter())` and implement this method as

```
public IFeedbackMessageFilter getFeedbackMessageFilter() {
    IFeedbackMessageFilter filter = null;
    if (RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT.equals(getConfigurationType())) {
        filter = new ErrorLevelFeedbackMessageFilter(FeedbackMessage.DEBUG);
    } else {
        filter = new ErrorLevelFeedbackMessageFilter(FeedbackMessage.ERROR);
    }
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for something Application wide so I wouldn't have to edit every FeedBackPanel but I had a feeling that was going to be the answer. Thanks.